# VueJS: Template Refs binding from slot props?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a component with a slot (SlotComponent) like this for example

```js
<template>
  <slot :element="element"></slot>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";
  const element = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null);

  onMounted(() => console.log(element.value));
</script>
```

However I can't seems to bind the element within the slot when using the component. The element is null on the onMounted lifecycle callback (above snippet).

```js
  <SlotComponent v-slot="{ element }">
    <div ref="element">hello world</div>
  </SlotComponent>
```

Question: how can I bind to the html element inside the slot?

Answer (score 0):

use [Function Refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#function-refs)

provide a `setElement()` function as a slot prop

```js
<template>
  <slot :set-element="setElement"></slot>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { ref, watchEffect } from "vue";
  const element = ref<Element | null>(null);

  function setElement(el: Element) {
    element.value = el;
  }

  watchEffect(() => {
    console.log(element.value);
  });
</script>
```

usage

```js
<SlotComponent v-slot="{ setElement }">
  <div :ref="(el) => setElement(el)">Hello World</div>
</SlotComponent>
```